# Dynamically generate Flask-RESTPlus routes

Tags: flask-restplus

I am trying to abstract away some of the route class logic (i.e. I am looking to dynamically generate routes).  `api.add_resource` seemed like the right place to do this.

So this is what I am trying to do:

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
from mylib import MyPost

# Define my model
json_model = api.schema_model(...)

api.add_resource(
    MyPost,
    '/acme',
    resource_class_kwargs={"json_model": json_model}
)
```

And then in mylib:

```
# mylib.py

def validate_endpoint(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return api.expect(json_fprint)(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

class MyPost(Resource):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Passed in via api.add_resource
        self.api = args[0]
        self.json_model = kwargs['json_model']

    # I can't do this because I don't have access to 'api' here...
    # @api.expect(json_model)

    # So I am trying to make this work
    @validate_endpoint
    def post(self):
        return {"data":'some data'}, 200
```

I don’t have access to the global api object here so I can’t call `@api.expect(json_model)`.  But I do have access to `api` and `json_model` inside of the post method.  Which is why I am trying to create my own `validate_endpoint` decorator.

This does not work though.  Is what I am trying to do here even possible?  Is there a better approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

**Stop using flask-restplus**. Thats the most valuable answer I can give you (and anyone else).

### Ownership is not there

Flask-restplus is a fork of flask-restful. Some engineers started developing features that suited them. The core guy has ghosted the project so its been officially forked again as  Flask-Restx.

### Poorly designed

I used to love flask when I was a yout’. I’ve realized since then that having global request, application, config that all magically update is not a good design. Their application factory pattern (to which flask-restplus conforms) is a style of statefully mutating the application object. First of all, Its hard to test. Second of all, it means that flask-restplus is wrapping the app and therefore all of the requests/handlers. How can anyone thing thats a good thing? A library whose main feature is endpoint documentation has its filthy hands all over every one of my requests?? (**btw, this is whats leading to your problem above)** Because my post is serious and thoughtful I’m skipping my thoughts on the Resource class pattern as it would probably push me into the waters of *ranting*.

### Random Feature Set

A good library has a single purpose and it does that single thing well. Flask-restplus does 15 things (masking, swagger generation, postman generation, marshaling, request arg validation). Some features you can’t even tell are in the libraries code by reading the docs.

## My solution to your problem

If you want to document your code via function decorators and models use a tool that does that alone and does it well. Use one that won’t touch your handlers or effect your actual request decorators. Use [oapispec](https://github.com/rayepps/oapispec) for swagger generation. For the other features of flask-restplus you’ve got [marshmallow](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow) for marshaling request/response data, [pydantic](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic) for validating request objects and args, and so on.

*btw, I know all this because I had to build an api with it. After weeks of fighting the framework I forked it, ripped it apart, created oapispec, and trashed it from the project.*